# How to repeat myself less with these function wrappers?

Tags: javascript, wrapper, dry, idioms

I'm going back to work on an old, and rather poorly coded, JS project of mine. In that project (it's a Thunderbird extension), I have the following:

```js
MyGlobalObject.Prefs = {

  preferencePrefix : "extensions.myextname.",

  getCharPref: function(prefName, defaultValue) {
    try {
      return Services.prefs.getCharPref(
        MyGlobalObject.Prefs.preferencePrefix + prefName);
    } catch(ex) {
      if (defaultValue != undefined)
        return defaultValue;
#ifdef DEBUG
      console.log("Failed obtaining string preference " + prefName);
#endif
      throw(ex);
    }
  },

  getIntPref: function(prefName, defaultValue) {
    try {
      return Services.prefs.getIntPref(
        MyGlobalObject.Prefs.preferencePrefix + prefName);
    } catch(ex) {
      if (defaultValue != undefined)
        return defaultValue;
#ifdef DEBUG
      console.log("Failed obtaining integer preference " + prefName);
#endif
      throw(ex);
    }
  },

  setCharPref: function(prefName, val) {
    Services.prefs.setCharPref(
      MyGlobalObject.Prefs.preferencePrefix + prefName, val);
  },

  setIntPref: function(prefName, val) {
    Services.prefs.setIntPref(
      MyGlobalObject.Prefs.preferencePrefix + prefName, val);
  },

  // etc. etc.
}
```

and, in fact, there's just about the same code for BoolPref. If I were reviewing this as C++ code, I'd say "template your wrappers on the preference type" (and maybe "write a preference proxy class"). But - this is Javascript. How should I best avoid repetition when wrapping my preference getters and setters? Or - maybe I shouldn't, and this is reasonable in JS?

Notes:

- I think I should stick to ECMAScript 6, but if you have a good argument against that, make it.
- `Services.prefs` adheres to the nsIPrefBranch interface, which I don't control. See [here](https://searchfox.org/comm-central/source/mozilla/modules/libpref/nsIPrefBranch.idl) or [here](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/embedding/embedapiref/embedapi83#1027388).

Comment: Looks like the place to refactor would be `getCharPref` and `getIntPref` to be more generic, like turn it into `getPref` and add an additional parameter. There are other approaches, but that'd probably be the best place to start

Comment: @CertainPerformance: But I don't control those...

Comment: Ah, are those built into the Thunderbird code?

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Yes, I'll edit to clarify that. Although you have given me an idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over an array of the types of preferences (char, int, bool) and use bracket notation to dynamically create the method names for the getter and setter:

```
const prefTypes = ['Char', 'Int', /* ... */];

MyGlobalObject.Prefs = {
    preferencePrefix: "extensions.myextname.",
};
for (const type of prefTypes) {
    const suffix = type + 'Pref';
    MyGlobalObject.Prefs['get' + suffix] = (prefName, defaultValue) => {
        try {
            return Services.prefs['get' + suffix](
                MyGlobalObject.Prefs.preferencePrefix + prefName);
        } catch (ex) {
            if (defaultValue != undefined)
                return defaultValue;
            // #ifdef DEBUG
            console.log("Failed obtaining " + type + " preference " + prefName);
            // #endif
            throw (ex);
        }
    };
    MyGlobalObject.Prefs['set' + suffix] = (prefName, val) => {
        Services.prefs['set' + suffix](
            MyGlobalObject.Prefs.preferencePrefix + prefName, val
        );
    };
}
```

Ideally, in this sort of situation, the `Services.prefs` and `MyGlobalObject.Prefs` shape would be refactored to take an additional argument instead - but this isn't possible in your case given the (arguably) badly designed third-party code which seems to encourage [WET-ness.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 0):

There is another JS module which may already take care of this for you: [Preferences.jsm](https://searchfox.org/comm-central/source/mozilla/toolkit/modules/Preferences.jsm).

It offers more generic methods, as described [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/JS_Modules#Preferences):

> The Preferences module provides an API for accessing application
> preferences. Getting and setting prefs is easy:
>
> ```
> let foo = Preferences.get("extensions.test.foo");
> Preferences.set("extensions.test.foo", "some value");
> ```
>
> ... datatypes are auto-detected, and you
> can pass a default value that the API will return if the pref doesn't
> have a value:
>
> ```
> let foo = Preferences.get("extensions.test.nonexistent", "default
> value"); // foo == "default value"
> ```
>
> ... the module
> returns undefined when you get a nonexistent pref without specifying a
> default value:
>
> ```
> let foo = Preferences.get("extensions.test.nonexistent"); // typeof
> foo == "undefined"
> ```

Assuming you're fine with this behavior, you should be able to just wrap these `set()` and `get()` methods, and not repeat yourself at all. Of course, you'll need to make sure that module is actually available to your code.